# Ranking tied results in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, rank

I have a MYSQL table which looks something like this:

```
ID | NAME CODE | SCORE
1: A01: 1
2: A01: 4
3: A01: 5
4: A02: 2
5: A02: 3
6: A02: 3
7: A02: 7
```

And the ranking outcome I am looking for is this (taking into account the 2 different NameCode groups):

```
ID | NAME CODE | SCORE | RANK

1: A01: 1: 1
2: A01: 4: 2
3: A01: 5: 3
4: A02: 2: 1
5: A02: 3: 2
6: A02: 3: 2
7: A02: 7: 4
```

I'm able to rank scores using the following code:

```
SELECT
  my_table.id,
  my_table.NameCode,
  my_table.Score,
  @prev := @curr,
  @curr := Score,
  @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank + @i) AS rank,
  IF(@prev <> Score, @i:=1, @i:=@i+1) AS counter
FROM
 my_table,
  (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 1, @i := 0  
  ) tmp_tbl
```

ORDER BY
     my_table.Score ASC

However this does not rank according to each NameCode group. It gives the following result:

```
ID | NAME CODE | SCORE | RANK

1: A01: 1: 1
2: A01: 4: 5
3: A01: 5: 6
4: A02: 2: 2
5: A02: 3: 3
6: A02: 3: 3
7: A02: 7: 7
```

Does anyone know the most efficient way I can rank within each NameCode group? Thanks.

Comment: can you please supply a [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of the create table  and inserts so we can bang this out for you. Otherwise, you are asking someone to do all that busy work first. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you want your logic to say if they are both the same repeat rank, if the name is the same then increment rank or else reset it back to 1

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    score,
    @rank := if(
        @name = name and @score = score, 
        @rank, 
        if(@name = name, @rank + 1, 1)
    ),
    @name := name, @score:= score
FROM your_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 1, @name := '', @score := 0) t;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40196/3)

EDIT: if you need the data sorted just do this

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    score,
    @rank := if(
        @name = name and @score = score, 
        @rank, 
        if(@name = name, @rank + 1, 1)
    ),
    @name := name, @score:= score
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM your_table
    ORDER BY name, score
) tt
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 1, @name := '', @score := 0) t;
```

[ORDERED FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3a8f/2)

EDIT2: if you want to rank them by placement meaning 1st place 2nd place. you can do this.

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    score,
    @rank := if(
        @name = name and @score = score, 
        @rank, 
        if(@name = name, @count + 1, 1)
    ),
    @count := @count + 1,
    if(@name != name, @count := 1, @count),
    @name := name, @score:= score
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 1, @count := 1, @name := '', @score := 0) t;
```

**[RANKED FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40196/15)**

Comment: @user1267980 no problem! glad I could help. If you have any more questions feel free to ask

Comment: @EoinS oh haha thank you! It should be really performant too because its not doing tons of scans on the table :)

Comment: John, what about ensuring the row after a tie is incremented by the number of tied rows, instead of just by 1?

Comment: @user1267980 not sure im following. want to edit your question with some data so I can see what you mean?

Comment: So using the data in your initial fiddle as an example, the scores for the second name group (A02) are 2,3,3,7. Instead if the rank being 1,2,2,3 ... I would like it to be 1,2,2,4. Any thoughts? Perhaps adding a counter would help?

Comment: And what's the criteria for it being a 4 instead of a 3?

Comment: Because let's say in a race, if 2 contestants are tied for 2nd place, then the next contestant finishes 4th, not 3rd. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @user1267980 ok I see. Yea thats easy to accomodate. Just added a solution

Comment: That's perfect! It's been bugging me for days, so now I can adapt it and incorporate it into my web service. Thanks again John.